# SQL Unique Constraint

Tags: sql, constraints

I have a table `Person` with a `Code(varchar)`, a `Name(varchar)` and `Active(bit)` fields. When I search for a `Person` only active records are returned, and when I delete a `Person` I set `Active = false` so that it does not show up in my Search.

The problem is I've added a Unique Constraint on the `Code` and `Name` fields, so that there can only be one of each `Person`. Problem is now the User doesn't see the `Person` in the Search (coz their active is false) and tries to add that same `Person` but the Unique constraint stops them from doing so.

Is there a way to keep the Unique constraint and maybe add a check to `Active` so that I can still add that `Person` if it was previously set as active = false? I know the easy solution here is to just delete the record completely but for data purposes I need to keep the record and not delete it hence only setting `active = false`.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you move archive data to the *separated* archive table?

Comment: Can you modify your constraint to include `Code`, `Name`, and `Active`?

Comment: @Yuck: It will prevent of having several `code+name` in deleted state (which is still perfectly a valid case)

Comment: @zerkms: To me those are still the same person even if they've been deleted. Sounds like duplicate data in the `Person` table if that's allowable.

Comment: @Yuck: they are archive records. I don't think it is a duplication having several obsolete rows for each person. It just happens when something changes.

Comment: @zerkms: Sounds like an *audit* table then and less of an *archive* table, IMHO.

Comment: @Yuck: audit table rows don't have any `active` state by definition (or I'm missing something). But that is not a topic to discuss I think ;-) We all agree that the better is to use separated table, don't we? :-)

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you apply a unique constraint to a field (or fields) then it is prevented from having any duplicate data.

Theoretically, you could apply the unique constraint over all three of your fields, but that would prevent you from being able to 'delete' a person if the same person existed in the table and was already 'deleted' (having active set to false).

I would personally archive the data rather than having an 'active' field if this is your concern.  Create a new table and insert the deletes in there to save the data and remove them from the existing 'Person' table.

Answer (score -2):

How about...

Remove the constraint, and do a count on the table. Before the insert just do a count on the table, to ensure that there are no duplicate records.

kind regards

Comment: In this case you need to lock the whole table to get the consistent state, or you'll have race condition issues otherwise.

Comment: As you stated 2 minutes ago the table will probably not contain more than 200 records at a time, at most.